# Using Python textwrap.shorten for string but with bytes width

Tags: python, word-wrap

I'd like to shorten a string using [`textwrap.shorten`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.shorten) or a function like it. The string can potentially have non-ASCII characters. What's special here is that **the maximal `width` is for the `bytes` encoding of the string**. This problem is motivated by the fact that several database column definitions and some message buses have a `bytes` based max length.

For example:

```py
>>> import textwrap
>>> s = '☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺'

# Available function that I tried:
>>> textwrap.shorten(s, width=27)
'☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ [...]'
>>> len(_.encode())
31  # I want ⩽27

# Desired function:
>>> shorten_to_bytes_width(s, width=27)
'☺ Ilsa, le méchant [...]'
>>> len(_.encode())
27  # I want and get ⩽27
```

It's okay for the implementation to use a width greater than or equal to the length of the whitespace-stripped placeholder `[...]`, i.e. 5.

The text should not be shortened any more than necessary. Some buggy implementations can use optimizations which on occasion result in excessive shortening.

[Using textwrap.wrap with bytes count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244817/) is a similar question but it's different enough from this one since it is about `textwrap.wrap`, not `textwrap.shorten`. Only the latter function uses a `placeholder` (`[...]`) which makes this question sufficiently unique.

**Caution**: Do not rely on any of the answers here for shortening a JSON encoded string in a fixed number of bytes. For it, substitute `text.encode()` with `json.dumps(text)`.

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809531/truncating-unicode-so-it-fits-a-maximum-size-when-encoded-for-wire-transfer) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665001/python-truncating-international-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory it's enough to `encode` your string, then check if it fits in the "width" constraint. If it does, then the string can be simply returned. Otherwise you can take the first "width" bytes from the encoded string (minus the bytes needed for the placeholder). To make sure it works like `textwrap.shorten` one also needs to find the last whitespace in the remaining bytes and return everything before the whitespace + the placeholder. If there is no whitespace only the placeholder needs to be returned.

Given that you mentioned that you really want it byte-amount constrained the function throws an exception if the placeholder is too large. Because having a placeholder that wouldn't fit into the byte-constrained container/datastructure simply doesn't make sense and avoids a lot of edge cases that could result in inconsistent "maximum byte size" and "placeholder byte size".

The code could look like this:

```py
def shorten_rsplit(string: str, maximum_bytes: int, normalize_spaces: bool = False, placeholder: str = "[...]") -> str:
    # Make sure the placeholder satisfies the byte length requirement
    encoded_placeholder = placeholder.encode().strip()
    if maximum_bytes < len(encoded_placeholder):
        raise ValueError('placeholder too large for max width')

    # Get the UTF-8 bytes that represent the string and (optionally) normalize the spaces.    
    if normalize_spaces:
        string = " ".join(string.split())
    encoded_string = string.encode()

    # If the input string is empty simply return an empty string.
    if not encoded_string:
        return ''

    # In case we don't need to shorten anything simply return
    if len(encoded_string) <= maximum_bytes:
        return string

    # We need to shorten the string, so we need to add the placeholder
    substring = encoded_string[:maximum_bytes - len(encoded_placeholder)]
    splitted = substring.rsplit(b' ', 1)  # Split at last space-character
    if len(splitted) == 2:
        return b" ".join([splitted[0], encoded_placeholder]).decode()
    else:
        return '[...]'
```

And a simple test case:

```py
t = '☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺'

for i in range(5, 50):
    shortened = shorten_rsplit(t, i)
    byte_length = len(shortened.encode())
    print(byte_length <= i, i, byte_length, shortened)
```

Which returns

```
True 5 5 [...]
True 6 5 [...]
True 7 5 [...]
True 8 5 [...]
True 9 9 ☺ [...]
True 10 9 ☺ [...]
True 11 9 ☺ [...]
True 12 9 ☺ [...]
True 13 9 ☺ [...]
True 14 9 ☺ [...]
True 15 15 ☺ Ilsa, [...]
True 16 15 ☺ Ilsa, [...]
True 17 15 ☺ Ilsa, [...]
True 18 18 ☺ Ilsa, le [...]
True 19 18 ☺ Ilsa, le [...]
True 20 18 ☺ Ilsa, le [...]
True 21 18 ☺ Ilsa, le [...]
True 22 18 ☺ Ilsa, le [...]
True 23 18 ☺ Ilsa, le [...]
True 24 18 ☺ Ilsa, le [...]
True 25 18 ☺ Ilsa, le [...]
True 26 18 ☺ Ilsa, le [...]
True 27 27 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant [...]
True 28 27 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant [...]
True 29 27 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant [...]
True 30 27 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant [...]
True 31 31 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ [...]
True 32 31 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ [...]
True 33 31 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ [...]
True 34 31 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ [...]
True 35 35 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ [...]
True 36 35 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ [...]
True 37 35 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ [...]
True 38 35 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ [...]
True 39 35 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ [...]
True 40 35 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ [...]
True 41 41 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺
True 42 41 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺
True 43 41 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺
True 44 41 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺
True 45 41 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺
True 46 41 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺
True 47 41 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺
True 48 41 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺
True 49 41 ☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺
```

The function also has an argument for normalizing the spaces. That could be helpful in case you have different kind of whitespaces (newlines, etc.) or multiple sequential spaces. Although it will be a bit slower.

### Performance

I did a quick test using [`simple_benchmark`](https://github.com/MSeifert04/simple_benchmark) (a library I wrote) to ensure it's actually faster.

For the benchmark I create a string containing random unicode characters where the (on average) one out of 8 characters is a whitespace. I also use half the length of the string as byte-width to split. Both have no special reason, it could bias the benchmarks though, that's why I wanted to mention it.
[image]

The functions used in the benchmark:

```py
def shorten_rsplit(string: str, maximum_bytes: int, normalize_spaces: bool = False, placeholder: str = "[...]") -> str:
    encoded_placeholder = placeholder.encode().strip()
    if maximum_bytes < len(encoded_placeholder):
        raise ValueError('placeholder too large for max width')
    if normalize_spaces:
        string = " ".join(string.split())
    encoded_string = string.encode()
    if not encoded_string:
        return ''
    if len(encoded_string) <= maximum_bytes:
        return string
    substring = encoded_string[:maximum_bytes - len(encoded_placeholder)]
    splitted = substring.rsplit(b' ', 1)  # Split at last space-character
    if len(splitted) == 2:
        return b" ".join([splitted[0], encoded_placeholder]).decode()
    else:
        return '[...]'

import textwrap

_MIN_WIDTH = 5
def shorten_to_bytes_width(text: str, width: int) -> str:
    width = max(_MIN_WIDTH, width)
    text = textwrap.shorten(text, width)
    while len(text.encode()) > width:
        text = textwrap.shorten(text, len(text) - 1)
    assert len(text.encode()) <= width
    return text

def naive(text: str, width: int) -> str:
    width = max(_MIN_WIDTH, width)
    text = textwrap.shorten(text, width)
    if len(text.encode()) <= width:
        return text

    current_width = _MIN_WIDTH
    index = 0
    slice_index = 0
    endings = ' '
    while True:
        new_width = current_width + len(text[index].encode())
        if new_width > width:
            break
        if text[index] in endings:
            slice_index = index
        index += 1
        current_width = new_width
    if slice_index:
        slice_index += 1  # to include found space
    text = text[:slice_index] + '[...]'
    assert len(text.encode()) <= width
    return text


MAX_BYTES_PER_CHAR = 4
def bytes_to_char_length(input, bytes, start=0, max_length=None):
    if bytes <= 0 or (max_length is not None and max_length <= 0):
        return 0
    if max_length is None:
        max_length = min(bytes, len(input) - start)
    bytes_too_much = len(input[start:start + max_length].encode()) - bytes
    if bytes_too_much <= 0:
        return max_length
    min_length = max(max_length - bytes_too_much, bytes // MAX_BYTES_PER_CHAR)
    max_length -= (bytes_too_much + MAX_BYTES_PER_CHAR - 1) // MAX_BYTES_PER_CHAR
    new_start = start + min_length
    bytes_left = bytes - len(input[start:new_start].encode())
    return min_length + bytes_to_char_length(input, bytes_left, new_start, max_length - min_length)


def shorten_to_bytes(input, bytes, placeholder=' [...]', start=0):
    if len(input[start:start + bytes + 1].encode()) <= bytes:
        return input
    bytes -= len(placeholder.encode())
    max_chars = bytes_to_char_length(input, bytes, start)
    if max_chars <= 0:
        return placeholder.strip() if bytes >= 0 else ''
    w = input.rfind(' ', start, start + max_chars + 1)
    if w > 0:
        return input[start:w] + placeholder
    else:
        return input[start:start + max_chars] + placeholder

# Benchmark

from simple_benchmark import benchmark, MultiArgument

import random

def get_random_unicode(length):  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/21666621/5393381
    get_char = chr
    include_ranges = [
        (0x0021, 0x0021), (0x0023, 0x0026), (0x0028, 0x007E), (0x00A1, 0x00AC), (0x00AE, 0x00FF), 
        (0x0100, 0x017F), (0x0180, 0x024F), (0x2C60, 0x2C7F), (0x16A0, 0x16F0), (0x0370, 0x0377), 
        (0x037A, 0x037E), (0x0384, 0x038A), (0x038C, 0x038C)
    ]

    alphabet = [
        get_char(code_point) for current_range in include_ranges
            for code_point in range(current_range[0], current_range[1] + 1)
    ]
    # Add more whitespaces
    for _ in range(len(alphabet) // 8):
        alphabet.append(' ')
    return ''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for i in range(length))

r = benchmark(
    [shorten_rsplit, shorten_to_bytes, shorten_to_bytes_width, naive, bytes_to_char_length],
    {2**exponent: MultiArgument([get_random_unicode(2**exponent), 2**exponent // 2]) for exponent in range(4, 15)},
    "string length"
)
```

I also did a second benchmark excluding the `shorten_to_bytes_width` function so I could benchmark even longer strings:

```py
r = benchmark(
    [shorten_rsplit, shorten_to_bytes, naive],
    {2**exponent: MultiArgument([get_random_unicode(2**exponent), 2**exponent // 2]) for exponent in range(4, 20)},
    "string length"
)
```

[image]

Comment: `shorten_rsplit()` might have a bug when it splits within a multi-byte character and there is no space left of it.

Comment: @zwirbeltier Thanks for the comment, do you have an example? Because I couldn't reproduce it with some examples I tried where it split within a non-ascii character.

Comment: MSeifert: Ah I see: When the first word is longer then the allowed bytes the input is completely ignored. Then your solution is a valid shortcut. It would break for slightly modified requirements though ie. `shorten('looooooong', 8) == 'loo[...]'`. Since you can rely on never needing to split within a word, and spaces have a 1Byte encoding everything’s good.

Comment: @zwirbeltier Yes, the approach doesn't truncate words. That's by design because I wanted it to behave similar to `textwrap.shorten`. However I have thought about providing a solution that also splits inside words but that's really complicated to get right, not just because there are multi-byte-characters but also graphemes (multiple characters that are combined so they are perceived as one character) and hyphenation (places where it makes sense to splt a word). There are libraries that handle that sort of thing but it's far more complicated and out of scope for this question.

Comment: `" ".join(string.split())` will lose some control characters, namely x0b, x0c, x1c, x1d, x1e, x1f. If this is unintended, replace it with the regular expressions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2077906/).

Answer (score 3):

This solution is inefficient, but it does appear to always work correctly and without ever shortening excessively. It serves as a canonical baseline for testing any efficient solutions.

It first shortens pretending that the text is an ASCII string; this can shorten insufficiently but never excessively. It then inefficiently shortens one character at a time, and no more than necessary.

```py
import textwrap

_MIN_WIDTH = 5  # == len(textwrap.shorten(string.ascii_letters, len(string.ascii_letters) - 1)) == len('[...]')


def shorten_to_bytes_width(text: str, width: int) -> str:
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56401167/
    width = max(_MIN_WIDTH, width)  # This prevents ValueError if width < _MIN_WIDTH
    text = textwrap.shorten(text, width)  # After this line, len(text.encode()) >= width
    while len(text.encode()) > width:
        text = textwrap.shorten(text, len(text) - 1)
    assert len(text.encode()) <= width
    return text
```

Credit: Thanks to Sanyash for an improvement.

### Test

```py
>>> s = '☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺'
>>> shorten_to_bytes_width(s, 27)
'☺ Ilsa, le méchant [...]'
>>> len(_.encode())
27
```

### Testing a candidate answer

Any candidate answer can be tested by comparing its outputs with the outputs of my function for `width` of `range(50, -1, -1)` or at minimum `range(50, 5, -1)`. Given a `candidate` function, the code below implements the unit test:

```py
import unittest

class TestShortener(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_candidate(self):
        text = '☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺'
        for width in range(50, -1, -1):
            with self.subTest(width=width):
                self.assertEqual(shorten_to_bytes_width(text, width), candidate(text, width))
```

Answer (score 2):

I will propose a naive solution with a loop and checking len of encoded characters like `len(text[index].encode())`. Also added timings for improvement proposed in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56401166/using-python-textwrap-shorten-for-string-but-with-bytes-width/56401167#comment99463896_56401167)

```
import textwrap, timeit

_MIN_WIDTH = 5

def A_B_B(text: str, width: int) -> str:
    width = max(_MIN_WIDTH, width)  # This prevents ValueError if width < _MIN_WIDTH
    text = textwrap.shorten(text, width)  # After this line, len(text.encode()) >= width
    while len(text.encode()) > width:
        text = textwrap.shorten(text, len(text) - 1)
    assert len(text.encode()) <= width
    return text

def naive(text: str, width: int) -> str:
    width = max(_MIN_WIDTH, width)  # This prevents ValueError if width < TEXTWRAP_MIN_WIDTH
    # textwrap.shorten does a lot of work like merging several spaces into one,
    # so we will use it first
    text = textwrap.shorten(text, width)
    if len(text.encode()) <= width:
        return text

    current_width = _MIN_WIDTH  # len of placeholder
    index = 0
    slice_index = 0  # we will do a slice on a last found space if necessary 
                     # (to avoid slicing in a middle of a word, for example)
    endings = ' '  # there also can be some more endings like \t \n
    while True:
        # we will use the fact that if str = str1 + str2 then
        # len(str.encode()) = len(str1.encode()) + len(str2.encode())
        new_width = current_width + len(text[index].encode()) # taking one more character
        if new_width > width:
            break
        if text[index] in endings:
            slice_index = index
        index += 1
        current_width = new_width
    if slice_index: # slice_index = 0 is a special case 
                    # when we dont go further than end of first word
        slice_index += 1  # to include found space
    text = text[:slice_index] + '[...]'
    assert len(text.encode()) <= width
    return text

s = '☺ Ilsa, le méchant ☺ ☺ gardien ☺'
n = 27

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: A_B_B(s, n), number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: naive(s, n), number=1000))
```

Timings:

```
0.032570790994213894
0.0206866109801922
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that tries to solve this problem directly without playing trial and error with `textwrap.shorten()` using different input strings.

It uses a recursive algorithm based on educated guesses about the minimum and maximum length of the string. Partial solutions (based on the guessed minimum length) are used to reduce the problem size quickly.

The solution has two parts:

1. `bytes_to_char_length()` computes the maximum number of chars in a string that fit within a number of bytes (see below for examples of how it works).
2. `shorten_to_bytes()` which uses the result of `bytes_to_char_length()` to calculate the placeholder position.

```py
MAX_BYTES_PER_CHAR = 4


def bytes_to_char_length(input, bytes_left, start=0, max_length=None):
    if bytes_left <= 0 or (max_length is not None and max_length <= 0):
        return 0

    if max_length is None:
        max_length = min(bytes_left, len(input) - start)

    bytes_too_much = len(input[start:start + max_length].encode()) - bytes_left
    if bytes_too_much <= 0:
        return max_length

    # Conservative estimate for the min_length assuming all chars at the end were
    # only 1 Byte.
    min_length = max(max_length - bytes_too_much, bytes_left // MAX_BYTES_PER_CHAR)
    # Generous estimate for the new max_length assuming all chars at the end of
    # max_string were MAX_BYTES_PER_CHAR sized.
    max_length -= (bytes_too_much + MAX_BYTES_PER_CHAR - 1) // MAX_BYTES_PER_CHAR

    # Now take `min_length` as a partial solution and call the function
    # recursively to fill the remaining bytes.
    new_start = start + min_length
    bytes_left -= len(input[start:new_start].encode())
    return min_length + bytes_to_char_length(input, bytes_left, new_start, max_length - min_length)


def shorten_to_bytes(text, byte_width, placeholder='', start=0):
    if len(text[start:start + byte_width + 1].encode()) <= byte_width:
        return text

    byte_width_p = byte_width - len(placeholder.encode())
    if byte_width_p <= 0:
        p = placeholder.strip()
        return p if len(p.encode()) <= byte_width else ''
    max_chars = bytes_to_char_length(text, byte_width_p, start)

    # Find rightmost whitespace if any
    w = text.rfind(' ', start, start + max_chars + 1)
    if w > 0:
        return text[start:w] + placeholder
    else:
        return text[start:start + max_chars] + placeholder
```

#### Examples for how `bytes_to_char_length()` works

For illustration purposes let’s assume each digit in the string is encoded to its value in bytes. So `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `'4'` take 1, 2, 3 and 4 Bytes respectively.

For `bytes_to_char_length('11111', 3)` we’ll get:

1. `max_length` is set to `3` by default.
2. The `input[start:start + max_length] = '111'` which has 3 Bytes, so `bytes_too_much = 0`
3. This is the exact size we were looking for so we’re done.

For `bytes_to_char_length('441111', 10)`:

1. `max_length` is set to `6`
2. `input[start:start + max_length] = '441111'` with 12 Bytes, so `bytes_too_much = 2`
3. `min_length` is set to `max_length - 2 == 4`. (It takes at maximum 2 characters to take up 2 Bytes).
4. `max_length` is reduced by 1 (It takes at least 1 character to take 2 Bytes).
5. `bytes_left = 0`, `max_length = 1`
6. Recursive call immediately returns `0` because there are no bytes left. Result is `min_length + 0 == 4`.

For `bytes_to_char_length('111144', 10)`:

1. `max_length` is set to `6` (as before)
2. `input[start:start + max_length] = '111144'` with 12 Bytes, so `bytes_too_much = 2`
3. `min_length` is set to `max_length - 2 == 4`
4. `max_length` is reduced by 1.
5. `new_start = 4`, `remaining_bytes = 6`, `max_length = 1`
6. Recursive call: `4 + bytes_to_char_length('111144', 6, start=4, max_length=1)`
7. `input[start:start + max_length] = '4'` with 4 Bytes, so `bytes_too_much = -2`
8. Immediately return from recursion by returning `max_length == 1`, return `5` as result.

---

Formally it makes the following assumptions:

- Each character takes at least one Byte in the encoded string.
- Each character takes at least `MAX_BYTES_BY_CHAR` in the encoded string.
- For two substrings if I split a string `s` into substrings `s == s1 + s2`, then `s.encode() == s1.encode() + s2.encode()`

#### Performance

- It should work smoothly even for long input strings, as it avoids copying the string.
- According to my timeit measurements it’s at about one order of magnitude faster for the simple test case.

Comment: Ah, yes and also it doesn’t split using words. I see. Both can be solved fairly easy though by working further processing the result of this function.

Comment: I’ve modified to solution to include actual wordwrapping and placing a placeholder.

Comment: @MSeifert: Thanks. I’ve improved it a bit still. Also it seems it’s the only function that actually takes a variable placeholder argument which might make it a bit slower.

Comment: Fixed that as well. Also added ` [...]` as default placeholder.

Comment: @A-B-B Both are fixed now.

Comment: It still has an unexpected output for widths 0...4 and 7...8 with the placeholder `' [...]'`. Please compare the output with that of my answer. I had added a unit test in my answer to assist with comparison over widths `range(50, -1, -1)`.